# Kotlinx Serialization - Custom serializer to ignore null value

Tags: kotlin, serialization, json-deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

Let's say I'm having a class like:

```
@Serializable
data class MyClass(
    @SerialName("a") val a: String?,
    @SerialName("b") val b: String
)
```

Assume the `a` is `null` and `b`'s value is "b value", then `Json.stringify(MyClass.serializer(), this)` produces:

```
{ "a": null, "b": "b value" }
```

Basically if `a` is `null`, I wanted to get this:

```
{ "b": "b value" }
```

From some research I found this is currently not doable out of the box with Kotlinx Serialization so I was trying to build a custom serializer to explicitly ignore `null` value. I followed the guide from [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md) but couldn't make a correct one.

Can someone please shed my some light? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not tested, just based on adapting the example):

```
@Serializable
data class MyClass(val a: String?, val b: String) {
    @Serializer(forClass = MyClass::class)
        companion object : KSerializer<MyClass> {
        override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = object : SerialClassDescImpl("MyClass") {
            init {
                addElement("a")
                addElement("b")
            }
        }

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj: MyClass) {
            encoder.beginStructure(descriptor).run {
                obj.a?.let { encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, obj.a) }
                encodeStringElement(descriptor, 1, obj.b)
                endStructure(descriptor)
            }
        }

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): MyClass {
            var a: String? = null
            var b = ""

            decoder.beginStructure(descriptor).run {
                loop@ while (true) {
                    when (val i = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                        CompositeDecoder.READ_DONE -> break@loop
                        0 -> a = decodeStringElement(descriptor, i)
                        1 -> b = decodeStringElement(descriptor, i)
                        else -> throw SerializationException("Unknown index $i")
                    }
                }
                endStructure(descriptor)
            }

            return MyClass(a, b)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `explicitNulls = false`

example:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
val format = Json { explicitNulls = false }
    
@Serializable
data class Project(
    val name: String,
    val language: String,
    val version: String? = "1.3.0",
    val website: String?,
)
    
fun main() {
    val data = Project("kotlinx.serialization", "Kotlin", null, null)
    val json = format.encodeToString(data)
    println(json) // {"name":"kotlinx.serialization","language":"Kotlin"}
}
```

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#explicit-nulls

Answer (score 3):

Use `encodeDefaults = false` property in `JsonConfiguration` and it won't serialize nulls (or other optional values)

Comment: This only works if you want to ignore all default values which isn't always the case. One example is WooCommerce where there is a "variation_id" if it doesn't exist you shouldn't pass that into an order as a line item, so the ideal path is to set it to null but WooCommerce doesn't accept null as a value. In this case it'd be nice for more fine grained control to say "ignore this value if it hasn't been set" or "ignore this value if it is null".

Answer (score 1):

`JsonConfiguration` is **deprecated** in favor of `Json {}` builder since kotlinx.serialization *1.0.0-RC* according to its [changelog](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-rc--2020-08-17).

Now you have to code like this:

```
val json = Json { encodeDefaults = false }
val body = json.encodeToString(someSerializableObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was also struggling with this one let me share with you the solution I found that is per property and does not require to create serializer for the whole class.

```
class ExcludeIfNullSerializer : KSerializer<String?> {

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): String {
        return decoder.decodeString()
    }

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
        get() = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ExcludeNullString", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: String?) {
        if (value != null) {
            encoder.encodeString(value)
        }
    }
}
```

will work as expected with the following class

```
@Serializable
    class TestDto(
        @SerialName("someString")
        val someString: String,
        @SerialName("id")
        @EncodeDefault(EncodeDefault.Mode.NEVER)
        @Serializable(with = ExcludeIfNullSerializer::class)
        val id: String? = null
    )
```

Note the @EncodeDefault(EncodeDefault.Mode.NEVER) is crucial here in case you using JsonBuilder with encodeDefaults = true, as in this case the serialization library will still add the 'id' json key even if the value of id field is null unless using this annotation.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, for anyone seeing this pos today, default values are not serialized (see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded-by-default)

So you simply add to set a default null value, and it will not be serialized.